# Empty a directory's contents into another directory while overwriting only duplicate files/directories

Tags: files, directory

I have two directories in `/var/www` one is a fresh install of [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) the other is a `git clone` of a Laravel application.

I basically need the Laravel application to move into the fresh install of Laravel so it can run properly with the requisite `/vendor` code.

However, I can't figure out how to use the command line to do this. I either `rsync` and delete the `/vendor` files because they aren't in the `git clone` or it doesn't overwrite anything.

```
-www
--laravelFresh
--laravelGithubApplication
```

I want everything in `laravelGithubApplication` to come out and overwrite everything in `laravelFresh` that is a duplicate. I don't want it to sync because whatever is in `laravelFresh` that doesn't have a duplicate in `laravelGithubApplication` shouldn't be overwritten.

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify __duplicate__. As in identical path/filename or identical in both filename and contents? Also "to come out" is not a common phrase. It could be interpreted as being removed, or moved to the destination directory instead of merely being copied.

Comment: @Deathgrip duplicate as in both. Come out means moved to destination directory, so `laravelGithubApplication` should be emtpy at the end. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to look at this differently. I believe you'll end up with what you want by copying from `laravelFresh` into `laravelGithubApplication`. Identical files don't matter which was used, files that are different you get the `laravelFresh` file, and any of the Github files that didn't exist in the fresh install remain.

Comment: @Deathgrip what command would I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

`mv laravelGithubApplication/* laravelFresh/`

Contents of directories before:

```
laravelGithubApplication/
laravelGithubApplication/file
laravelFresh/
laravelFresh/file
laravelFresh/vendor/
laravelFresh/vendor/file
```

Contents of directories after:

```
laravelGithubApplication/
laravelFresh/
laravelFresh/file (overwritten)
laravelFresh/vendor/
laravelFresh/vendor/file
```

As you wish, duplicate files (`file`) have been overwritten; existing directories (`vendor`) remain untouched; and everything has "come out" of `laravelGithubApplication/`.

Comment: Doesn't work, `directory not empty`.

Comment: Oh, you also have duplicate directories. In that case, you need `cp -R laravelGithubApplication/* laravelFresh/` but you lose the emptying of the src directory.

Comment: No that just gives me a wrong directory structure, so if I have a duplicate directory it puts it as a subdirectory. So laravelFresh/app becomes /laravelFresh/app/app. That's not what I want. I want any duplicates to be overwritten.

Comment: Eh, sorry about that. Works fine for me. Directory structure is intact. I can only suggest editing your original question with a before/after directory listing so someone else can try.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from our q&a in the comments try this (assuming everything is under /var/www):

```
# cd /var/www
# mkdir laravelCombined
# cd laravelGithubApplication
# find . | cpio -dumpv /var/www/laravelCombined
# cd ../laravelFresh
# find . | cpio -dumpv /var/www/laravelCombined
```

Before removing the contents of `/var/www/laravelGithubApplication` and `/var/www/laravelCombined` check that what is in `/var/www/laravelCombined` is what you need. If it is:

```
# rm -rf /var/www/laravelGithubApplication
# rm -rf /var/www/laravelFresh
# mv /var/www/laravelCombined /var/www/laravelFresh
```